# Azure Function 'unable to find module' after following installation instructions

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions

I'm trying trying to use a node module inside my Azure Functions project. I've tried following [these instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node#node-version-and-package-management) several times but still can't use the module I'm trying to bring in.
After bringing in my package.json and running `npm install`, I can see the node_modules folder (actual modules are located in node_modules/.staging). Upon restarting the function and trying to run it, I get `Error: Cannot find module '_____'`.
I'm following the instructions correctly. Any suggestions on how to get the modules to work?

Comment: Another option for handling node modules that may be helpful in the long run: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-pack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did everything correctly, after `npm install`, please wait for some time. Modules being in `./staging` folder means the installation is still in progress.

You will see added packages prompt in console after the installation is finished.

**Update**--Avoid long time waiting for module install.

As @brettsam mentioned in comment, with [azure-functions-pack tool](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-pack)(also a module), we can place all the modules in a single file, no need to install online and wait. You can search for your function name to find your function scripts if you want to edit after publication.

Comment: Thanks, Jerry. Does the file structure inside the node_modules folder change at all once the installation is complete?

Comment: @TaylorKrusen the staging folder should have gone then and you can see the modules you installed.